# Is it a good idea to use <a href="http://name.com" rel="noindex, nofollow">name</a> in this situation?

Tags: seo, search-engine, yahoo, bing

I have a network of about 200 blogs (Wordpress Multisite), and all of them show links to all the other ones on a sidebar on the right hand side (basically 200+ links on the right hand side of every single page). I have it set to rel="nofollow" now, but I was wondering if changing it to rel="noindex, nofollow" would be a good idea?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Are you concerned about server performance or about a search engine degrading your pagerank?

Comment: why not remove the lot of them and only show ~10 links

Comment: because they generate quite a lot of traffic to other sites (evey site out of 200 to other 199 sites)

Comment: I don't believe that users look through a list of 200 links. Most of that traffic is probably from bots ignoring the rel attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I am just showing a lot of these urls in Google Analytics. That's why I was thinking it is coming from clicks.

Comment: It looks to me like noindex does not apply to the rel attribute, just to the meta tag. Also they should be space-separated, rather than comma-separated. I'm not sure, but I think this page includes the list of allowed values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### nofollow

`nofollow` only means that a bot *should* not follow this link. If you are concerned only about Google (as your tag suggests) this will probably be of help:

> **How does Google handle nofollowed links?**
>
> In general, we don't follow them. This means that Google does not
>   transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially,
>   using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall
>   graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our
>   index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the
>   URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap. Also, it's important to
>   note that other search engines may handle nofollow in slightly
>   different ways.
>   [[Source]](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569)

However, adding this attribute is in no way a hard restriction, there is no standard, and some bots may ignore it altogether. Also, search engines may *still* flag the page as a linkbuilding site depending on content/link ratio.

### noindex

`noindex` is not used in links by Google (I do not know about others). It is meant for the robots `<meta>` attribute in the html header and applies to the whole page. So it is most likely no use for you. Example:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>
```

### linkbuilding

200 links are however not very user-friendly either. You should seriously consider reducing the number of links by (for example) selecting those that have a similar topic.

As you read this, look to the right, yes, here on Stack Overflow, there is a "Box" titled **Related**. This is how you do it. Imagine them putting *every single topic ever created* in there... Not very useful.

Also if you do this with some logic like I suggested above and not just randomly selecting N links from the list, you can probably remove the `nofollow`, since the links will become useful and Google likes useful links.

You could then also add a "spotlight" for low-traffic sites (those would probably need the nofollow though)