# Request Search Engines not to index a specific span on a web page

Tags: html, indexing, search-engine

I know this question was [asked 8 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058530/how-to-prevent-search-engines-from-indexing-a-span-of-text) and there was no workable answer. Hoping things may have changed...

I have a website, lets call it isellwebshops.com. That website advertises web shops to a particular type of business that requires a shop to sell products provided by us but sold under their franchise.

The actual shops all sit under the same URL, lets call it thisismywebshop.com?=uniquestorecode

I need to advertise thisismywebshop.com on the website isellwebshops.com. But what we are really selling is the service, not the brand. however, I need to tell people the brand when they sign up, so on thisismywebshop.com, I need something like:

```
<p>Create your <span>isellwebshops.com</span> account here</p>
```

But, I don't want search engines indexing the span. Reason being, end users of thisismywebshop.com, search for it, then sometimes click the wrong link to come to the isellwebshops.com instead of going to where they really needed to go. Sounds crazy, but it happens enough to be a problem for us. Even though the sites are clear in their wording etc.

I've researched this: `<span class="robots-nocontent">` as per the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058530/how-to-prevent-search-engines-from-indexing-a-span-of-text)

But that doesn't seem to stop Google or Bing.

Is there a way to stop a span from being indexed whilst maintaining an index of the page?

Comment: Solution from the webmasters stack: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)