# Equivalent <!--googleoff : index--> for other browsers

Tags: html, indexing

Can you say me if an equivalent of the html tag "googleoff:index" exists for other browsers ?
I'm searching a way to avoid the indexation of just a part of my web pages, if you have other way to do that tell me please. :)

Thank you !

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685205/noindex-tag-for-google/15718255#15718255.  Also I don't think those tags stop google from indexing those parts of the page: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/can-you-use-googleon-and-googleoff-comments-to-prevent-googlebot-from-indexing-p?lq=1

Comment: Tanks for your answer